# How to display css animated text inline with normal text?

Tags: css

I'm trying to display a sentence where only a few words in the sentence are animated by CSS. While I can get the words inline using `<span>`, the animation stops working. If I wrap it in something else like `<p>` the animation works but doesn't display inline.

```css
.scary p {
  animation: .8s shake infinite alternate;
}

.scary span {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: .8s shake infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes shake {
  0% { transform: skewX(-15deg); }
  5% { transform: skewX(15deg); }
  10% { transform: skewX(-15deg); }
  15% { transform: skewX(15deg); }
  20% { transform: skewX(0deg); }
  100% { transform: skewX(0deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="scary">
  Something has gone <p>terribly wrong</p>, what should we do?
</div>
<br>
<div class="scary">
  Something has gone <span>terribly wrong</span>, what should we do?
</div>
```

How can I display inline text that is animated?

Comment: Not the problem, but your HTML processor is set to Pug in your codepen, causing issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the display of the `span` to `inline-block`. It has to be `inline-block` specifically and not `inline` or `block` since the animation uses `skew`, which only works on things that aren't `inline`, and you also need the block itself to be inline, hence `inline-block`.

```css
.scary p {
  animation: .8s shake infinite alternate;
}

.scary span {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: .8s shake infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes shake {
  0% { transform: skewX(-15deg); }
  5% { transform: skewX(15deg); }
  10% { transform: skewX(-15deg); }
  15% { transform: skewX(15deg); }
  20% { transform: skewX(0deg); }
  100% { transform: skewX(0deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="scary">
  Something has gone <p>terribly wrong</p>, what should we do?
</div>
<br>
<div class="scary">
  Something has gone <span>terribly wrong</span>, what should we do?
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the prompt reply.